# django связи ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, модель

всех приветствую, столкнулся с проблемой, рад буду любому совету.
имеется 3 модели user -> компания -> транспорт, все они связаны ForeignKey.
когда пользователь проходит аутентификацию ему предлагается зарегистрировать свою компанию, это уже реализовано, компания создается и в нее я вкладываю id пользователя
а как в транспорт вложить id компании (именно той которую он создал )
и соответственно как в дальнейшем выводить пользователю транспортные средства которые принадлежат его компании.
как все это делать с 1 связью я понимаю, сравнивать ключи и выводить в шаблон, а вот как работать с тремя связями...?

models.py

```
class clients(models.Model):
...
user = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, default = None)
...

class transport(models.Model):
...
id_client = models.ForeignKey('clients', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, default = None, blank = True)
...
```

во вью пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде этого

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form_ts = form_transport(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_ts.is_valid():
            instance = form_ts.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.client_id = clent.id(user=request.user.id)
            instance.save()
            done = 'ТС занесено успешно, продолжайте'
            #return redirect('/transport')

        else:
            error = 'Проверьте форму!'
```

Comment: вы можете добавить ваш models.py ?

Comment: дополнил описание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете в вашу форму передавать пользоваться (`request.user`) или сами компании, чтобы ограничить выбор из всех компаний.

Примерно так:

```py
class form_transport(...):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        company_field = self.fields.get('<поле выбора компании в форме>')
        if user:
            company_field.queryset = clients.objects.filter(user=user)
        else:
            compamy_field.queryset = clients.objects.none()  # Чтобы нельзя было выбрать компанию другого юзера
```

и передавайте юзера во view

```
form = form_transport(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
```

Используйте это и ваш вопрос

> соответственно как в дальнейшем выводить пользователю транспортные средства которые принадлежат его компании.

будет решен

---

PS: Если передавать сами компании - то нужно передавать `QuerySet`

Comment: спасибо большое, это именно то что нужно было и даже больше )

Answer (score 0):

ответ оказался слишком примитивным, возможно это кому-то поможет

создал переменную

```
q = clients.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)[0]
```

записал ее в поле

```
instance.client = q
```

Comment: не поможет, если у юзера несколько компаний

Comment: так и есть, на данный момент у пользователя может быть только 1 компания, но вскоре это может измениться, как только появиться выбор можно будет воспользоваться схемой которую пописал Za Ars